# Making a (more) general converter for simple values

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I've used the following two extension methods for converting the incoming strings into what I need them to be. They are used on data that has been converted to strings, but where the original type is **always** known.

```
public static int ToInt(this string self)
{
  try { return Convert.ToInt32(self); }
  catch { return default(int); }
}

public static double ToInt(this string self)
{
  try { return Convert.ToDouble(self); }
  catch { return default(double); }
}
```

I just learned that the information flow is going to be extended and contain other types, as well. Adding a new extension method for each is a sure way to insanity in the long run, not to mention code redundancy. So I attempted to make it more general.

```
public static T ToType<T>(this string self)
{
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    try { return Convert.ToInt32(self); }
    catch { return default(int); }
}
```

However, the compiler has issues with that (regarding type, of course). I've tried casting in the first return, and using the provided type in the second, but the issue still remains.

```
public static T ToType<T>(this string self)
{
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    try { return (T)Convert.ToInt32(self); }
    catch { return default(T); }
}
```

Can it be done at all, or am I going to end up creating many similar extension methods? Please keep in mind that since I will always know what types are being served, I only need to cover those, in case a fully generic and type safe approach isn't possible, or is very cumbersome.

Also, please note that I had surgery yesterday, and I'm still a bit off, so the answer might be embarrassingly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the lines of [another question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/732694/1525840), you can accomplish this using *Convert.ChangeType()* method.

```
public static T Get<T>(this String self)
{
  return (T)Convert.ChangeType(self, typeof(T));
}
```

Or even more sophisticated version with a fallback in case the conversion fails.

```
public static T Get<T>(this String self, T fallBack = default(T))
{
  try { return (T)Convert.ChangeType(self, typeof(T)); }
  catch { return fallBack; }
}
```

The usage is then as follows.

```
String source = ...
Guid guid = source.Get<Guid>();
int number = source.Get<int>(42);
```

Comment: I took the liberty to adapt a bit to this case. Hope you like it. Also, you might want to remove the comment now.

Comment: Apparently, I forgot to check your answer as accepted. My bad. Better late than never, I guess. You should have reminded. The voting system is vital for quality assurance, even if one feels like a nagging looser reminding of voting. Which brings me to my part of it - don't forget to vote up if you've found the question to be interesting and rewarding.